# I have three columns in SQL and I am trying to get all columns that match

Tags: sql, relational-division

Desired Result: Find everyone who has purchased both gum and baskets.

Example:
(However, just about every column is stored on different tables.)

[image: Example]

Comment: Please declare your RDBMS and version, provide table definition(s) (`CREATE TABLE` statement(s)), and sample values as *text*, never as image.

Comment: I couldn't make sense of this: `(However, just about every column is stored on different tables.)` - nor the title, for that matter.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Desired Result: Find everyone who has purchased both gum and baskets.

This is a typical case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).
Assuming a UNIQUE (or PK) constraint on `(name, purchase)` a query like this does the job:

```
SELECT name
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (name)
WHERE  t1.purchase = 'Gum'
AND    t2.purchase = 'Baskets';
```

See:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Comment: All of the purchases are on the same table in the same column. That's what makes it so hard.

Comment: @Skinny That's also what makes it relational division. (I am using a single table.)